# how to delete row in excel with python pywin32

Tags: excel, python-3.6, pywin32

Dear, All.

If cells (i,5) does not have value, I want to delete the row in excel with python pywin32 at python 3.6.

this is my code.

```
def qms(self):
    fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)

    if fname[0]:
        self.Filename.setText(fname[0])
        excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        excel.Visible = True
        f = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname[0])
        fs = f.ActiveSheet
        lastrow = fs.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        for i in range(3, lastrow):
            if not fs.Cells(i,5).Value :
               fs.getCells().deleteRows(i-1,1,True)

        excel.Workbooks.save()
        excel.Quit()
```

I think there are problem in fs.getCells().deleteRow(i-1,1,True).
I cannot understand. could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(lastrow, 2, -1):
    if fs.Cells(i,5).Value != ""
        fs.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete()
```

or you can probably delete all at once:

```
fs.UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(5).SpecialCells(4).EntireRow.Delete()
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel

Comment: thank you for help me.
but i can't understand fs.UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(5).SpecialCells(4).EntireRow.Delete()

Answer (score 0):

```
def qms(self):
    fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)

    if fname[0]:
        self.Filename.setText(fname[0])
        excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        excel.Visible = True
        f = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname[0])
        fs = f.ActiveSheet
        lastrow = fs.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        for i in range(lastrow, 2, -1):
            if fs.Cells(i,5).Value == None or fs.Cells(i,5).Value == "":
                fs.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete()
```